# TS Error: Type 'string' is not an array type or a string type. How a string is not a string?

Tags: typescript, spread-syntax

TS throws strange error:

> Error:(125, 18) TS2569: Type 'string' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.

How comes a string is not a string?

I want to see how TS is going to compile spread operator for a string.

My code in browser console. A string is broken up into characters:

```js
> s = 'abcdef';
> r = [...s];
< (6) ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

My code in TS:

```js
const s: string = 'abcdef';
const res = [...s]; // <= Error: Type 'string' is not an array type or a string type
console.log(res);
```

Why?

TS version:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
```

UPD:

@VtoCorleone 
A screenshot
[image]

UPD:

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "downlevelIteration": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "files": [
    "sample.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but have you tried adding `"downlevelIteration": true` to your `tsconfig`?

Comment: @OliverRadini, Yes, I did both, `true` and `false`. TS doesn't blow when `true` as expected. But why is it complaining a string is not a string?

Comment: I just copy and pasted your exact example with TS `3.5.1` and got no warnings or errors.

Comment: What are you targeting? In the [TS playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?downlevelIteration=true&target=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBBBccoCcCWYDmMC8MDkAhgEbAAmApgGZ4DcAUKJLMuRDjANoB0PEAujRgB6ITAA8uAKLJkIZIgAqATwAO5fNDSY8MVGzAhYBMDAIyCSmFFXq5ppFqzW1DcBBAAbclw8gMAChYIAEoaIA) I get errors if I target ES5 or below...

Comment: There's [certainly an error](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?downlevelIteration=true&target=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBBccoCcCWYDmMC8MDkAhgEbAAmApgGZ4DcAUKJLMuRDjANoB0PEAujRgB6ITAA8uACoBPAA7l80NJjwxUbMCFgEwMAsmQFpMKHIUhkMOiJikQrGJtgALAgDcFBfBwDK0gLZEIAA2XKhQ5IZQFnwAFACUqv7kUM4gpCauzCkArsiQerrhkQTRyFwM4BAh5FzBIBixLBDxNEA) but I can't reproduce anything saying `"string" is not a string`.  I just see `"string" is not an array", which is true.  Can you reproduce the error in a linkable web IDE?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, indeed `"target": "es5",`. I've updated the question with my `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Your code starts on line 132. Can there be any conflicting code above? Are you trying to redefine `s`? What happens when you put the code in a new file?

Answer (score 31):

To expand on Heretic Monkey's comment:

Changing target from `es5` to `es2015` or `es6` fixes the issue. Here's my full `tsconfig.json` for clarity:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

[Working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?downlevelIteration=true&target=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBBBccoCcCWYDmMC8MDkAhgEbAAmApgGZ4DcAUKJLMuRDjANoB0PEAujRgB6ITAA8uACoBPAA7l80NJjwxUbMCFgEwMAsmQFpMKHIUhkMOiJikQrGJtgALAgDcFBfBwDK0gLZEIAA2XKhQ5IZQFnwAFACUqv7kUM4gpCauzCkArsiQerrhkQTRyFwM4BAh5FzBIBixLBDxNEA)

Side note: `"downlevelIteration": true` also fixed it, but that doesn't seem like the correct solution to me.

Answer (score 4):

I have Angular-CLI (8) - in my case modification `tsconfig.json` in key `"target": "es2015"` (or es2018) not helps at all. Only adding `"downlevelIteration": true` helps. Here is my whole file

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```