# Typescript loop through string with index and value

Tags: typescript

I want to loop through a string and I want to have both the index and the character at this index. I know I could use a simple for loop for this, but I thought some of the newer features of Javascript/Typescript might be more elegant, so I tried this:

```js
for (const [i, character] of Object.entries('Hello Stackoverflow')) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(typeof(i));
    console.log(character);
}
```

Amazingly this works, however even though `i` counts up, it is a string. So for example this 
doesn't work:

```js
'other string'.charAt(i)
```

I'm new at Typescript, so my questions are:

- Why is i a string and not a number?
- Is there a simpler / more elegant way to do this?

Comment: `i` is a number.

Comment: i outputs '1' '2' and so on, and typeof(i) prints 'string'

Comment: Yeah, my bad, didn't realise that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The unicode-safe way would be to split to characters using spread syntax:

```
const chars = [...text];
```

Then you iterate using good old `Array.prototype.forEach`

```
chars.forEach((c, i) => console.log(c, i));
```

Comment: Looks elegant however I get this error for `const chars = [...text];`: 

`Type 'string' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.ts(2569)`

Comment: "Type 'string' is not an array type or a string type" --- this looks awkward: what exactly your `text` is? @Vladtn

Comment: Changing target from es5 to es2015 or es6 fixes the issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59662571/331719

Answer (score 9):

> Why is i a string and not a number?

Because `Object.entries()` returns a key-value pair and is intended to be used for objects, where keys are of course strings.

> Is there a simpler / more elegant way to do this?

Just a simple for loop with `charAt(i)` can do the trick:

```js
const text = 'Hello StackOverflow';
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  const character = text.charAt(i);
  console.log(i, character);
}
```

Comment: `text.charAt` could break unicode characters. Try with `const text = '‍‍‍';`

Comment: @bauke So what I would have done in plain Javascript anyway, thanks! :)

Comment: @Fels it's broken though